# What explains self destructive behaviour?

Tags: psychology

I was recently playing chess and lost a few games back to back. I don't know why but I played several games after that and lost all of them deliberately. Making it extremely easy for the opponent to defeat me. (eg: handing over all my pieces to be killed). I lost 100 Elo rating points which I had worked hard to attain. Has anybody else been in this mental zone where you just go into ultimate self destructive mode? or have you come across a player like that?

Answer (score 3):

People do this all the time when they are frustrated, not just in chess. The term is called tilting. I've fallen victim to this state many times.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilt_(poker)

A notable example of a top player tilting is Duda in his match against Nakamura in the recent Chess.com Global Championship Finals, where Nakamura was leading 3-0 in their 4 game match, and Duda began the final game with 1.e3? and 2. Ke2?!

Nakamura went on to win their match that day 4-0.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a wonder if not (therefore I suggest to rephrase your question a bit, forist surely will make helpful suggestions how).

I myself most definitely am an example, for fuzzy values of "deliberately". It just happened in this years German seniors championship. I come into the venue in the 6th round, and the arbiter tells me that the opponent forfeited due to sickness.§ This put me into a mental state of "Even if I should win this tournament, I don't deserve it, and Karma will be evened by WW3 starting. Or suchlike. Has happened before." Consequently, I played much worse for the rest of the tournament and literally got my posterior handed to me the last round.

§Which is always a danger in a senior tournament with Swiss and overnight pairings. Happened again in the Hamburg ch, but there I was the high favorite anyway, thus didn't fell into this trap and won big time. (And yet, WWIII still hasn't started.)